# Git: commit missing

Tags: git, commit, reset

I don't know how, it seems that I've lost some `git commit`.

I've started with a commit named: `Drawing datas in rates-heatmap directive, needs to be correctly positioned`

Then I did some work and several commits, no stash, no rebase, no checkout. Only commit.

Then I wrong edit a file  (line 485)
and run: `git reset --hard`, (line 489)
made some edit, commit that (line 499)
 and now all the commits done before the fist (line 370) are missing.

Any idea on how to retrieve them?

Here is my bash History:

```
  370  git commit -m "Drawing datas in rates-heatmap directive, needs to be correctly positioned"
  ...
  475  git commit -m "HeatMap and chart resize fixed"
  ...
  482  git commit -m "Moved pre-commit in pre-push"
  483  cd Sites/motusq
  484  cd Sites/motusquo_admin/
  485  vim .git/hooks/pre-commit
  486  git status
  487  git diff prepush.sh
  488  git reset --jard
  489  git reset --hard
  490  rm -rf .git/hooks
  491  git status
  492  npm install
  493  ls .git
  494  mkdir .git/hooks
  495  npm install
  496   <:#<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:a<:
  497  git status
  498  git add package.json
  499  git commit -m "Linked prepush script"
```

Here is the output from `git log`:

```
commit c51add23b302401cc707ce78cbdc7d2cebebecd1
Author: Matteo Scandolo
Date:   Wed Sep 16 12:33:22 2015 +0200

Linked prepush script

commit 23bb7ad9fc939b4fced8787d113194c6b66cea31
Author: Matteo Scandolo
Date:   Mon Sep 14 17:04:31 2015 +0200

Drawing datas in rates-heatmap directive, needs to be correctly positioned

commit c2f3637e9d51e4632ceefa5019b4430de9ae06e4
Author: Matteo Scandolo <matteo.scandolo@link-me.it>
Date:   Mon Sep 14 14:55:13 2015 +0200
```

Also tried `git reflog`, but same situation:

```
 c51add2 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from feature/rates to feature/rates
 c51add2 HEAD@{1}: commit: Linked prepush script
 23bb7ad HEAD@{2}: commit: Drawing datas in rates-heatmap directive, needs to be correctly positioned
 c2f3637 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/rates
 c2f3637 HEAD@{4}: commit: Generated fake data
 5558ed7 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from master to develop
```

Any idea on how to restore that commit?

Comment: That is not the output of git reflog!

Answer (score 0):

Look at `git reflog`. It should show the previous version of HEAD (before your last commit) as `HEAD@{1}`.

You can run `git log HEAD@{1}` to confirm it shows the right history, or add a branch or tag to that commit, and then browse all refs. Once you can see what happened, you can use merge or rebase to repair your history.

For browsing, you can use `gitk --all` for graphical browsing, or `git log --graph --full-history --all --decorate` to see it in the terminal.

---

About the comments:

If you committed something, and it doesn't show up in reflog, the possibilities are:

1. it happened too long ago and fell off the end. That seems unlikely here, unless a lot more happened than is shown in your history
2. you're looking at the wrong repo/reflog
3. the commit *failed* and you didn't notice

If the commit succeeded, advancing HEAD, the reflog should have been updated immediately, so there's no obvious way for the commit to get lost.

---

Further note: the output edited into the question is *not* from `git reflog` - it should look something like

```
$ git reflog
9436c1a HEAD@{0}: commit (amend): TASK-209.
58a0687 HEAD@{1}: commit (amend): TASK-209
...
89acb5d HEAD@{6}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/task209
89acb5d HEAD@{7}: rebase -i (fixup): initial work
7560e14 HEAD@{8}: rebase -i (fixup): updating HEAD
304b5a4 HEAD@{9}: rebase -i (fixup): # This is a combination of 16 commits.
...
d3e7529 HEAD@{39}: checkout: moving from task209 to d3e7529
5267db8 HEAD@{40}: commit: fixup format, sketch events
0e23e6f HEAD@{41}: commit: Combine new top-level code with existing version.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already tried with `git reflog` but my commits are not there. Any other way?

Comment: They really should be. Your bash history shows you changing directory - are you certain you're looking at the same repo you committed to?

Comment: Yes sure, I closed and reopen the shell, so I had to come back in the repo folder.